# C# Encoding.Convert Vs C++ MultiByteToWideChar

Tags: c#, character-encoding, utf-16

I have a C++ code snippet that uses MultiByteToWideChar to convert UTF-8 string to UTF-16

For C++, if input is "HÃ´tel", the output is "Hôtel" which is correct

For C#, if input is "HÃ´tel", the output is "HÃ´tel" which is not correct.

The C# code to convert from UTF8 to UTF16 looks like

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(
            Encoding.Convert(
                Encoding.UTF8,
                Encoding.Unicode,
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8)));
```

In C++ the conversion code looks like

```
MultiByteToWideChar(
    CP_UTF8,            // convert from UTF-8
    0,                  // default flags
    utf8.data(),        // source UTF-8 string
    utf8.length(),      // length (in chars) of source UTF-8 string
    &utf16[0],          // destination buffer
    utf16.length()      // size of destination buffer, in wchar_t's
    )
```

I want to have the same results in C# that I am getting in C++. Is there anything wrong with the C# code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you want to treat string characters as Windows-1252 (Often mislabeled as ANSI) code points, and have those code points decoded as UTF-8 bytes, where `Windows-1252 code point == UTF-8 byte value`.

The reason the accepted answer doesn't work is that it treats the string characters as unicode code points, rather than
Windows-1252. It can get away with most characters because Windows-1252 maps them exactly the same as unicode, but input with characters
like `–`, `€`, `™`, `‘`,  `’`, `”`, `•` etc.. will fail because Windows-1252 maps those differently than unicode in this sense.

So what you want is simply this:

```
public static string doWeirdMapping(string arg)
{
    Encoding w1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(w1252.GetBytes(arg));
}
```

Then:

```
Console.WriteLine(doWeirdMapping("HÃ´tel")); //prints Hôtel
Console.WriteLine(doWeirdMapping("HVOLSVÃ–LLUR")); //prints HVOLSVÖLLUR
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this one:

```
private static string Utf8ToUnicode(string input)
{
  return   Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input.Select(item => (byte)item).ToArray()); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not always work ! Not sure why. For instance for a UTF8 string "HVOLSVÃ–LLUR" should get converted to "HVOLSVÖLLUR" as it does in C++ but not in C#. I think I will rather use pInvoke on MultiByteToWideChar

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 string str = "abc!";

            Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
            Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

            byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(str);

            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert( unicode,
                                                 utf8,
                                                 unicodeBytes );

            Console.WriteLine( "UTF Bytes:" );
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach( byte b in utf8Bytes ) {
                sb.Append( b ).Append(" : ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine( sb.ToString() );
```

[This Link](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/) would be helpful for you to understand about encodings and their conversions

Comment: This is same as the C# code I pasted in my post and gives the output as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString().`

Pass in your UTF-8 encoded text, as a byte array. The function returns a standard .net string which is encoded in UTF-16.

Sample function will be as below:

```
private string ReadData(Stream binary_file) {
  System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
  // Read string from binary file with UTF8 encoding
  byte[] buffer = new byte[30];
  binary_file.Read(buffer, 0, 30);
  return encoding.GetString(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not work for the input string I have mentioned